# Different test unit output in Rubymine and console

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, output, rubymine

When I run unit tests from RubyMine the output looks like this:

```
C:\Ruby\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) "C:/Users/User/RubymineProjects/Unijet Customer Data Cleanup/Test_unijet_customer_data_cleanup.rb"
##teamcity[enteredTheMatrix timestamp = '2014-11-24T12:11:50.801+0100']
##teamcity[testCount count = '1' timestamp = '2014-11-24T12:11:50.801+0100']
```

When I execute the tests from the console I get this output:

```
Loaded suite C:/Users/User/RubymineProjects/Unijet Customer Data Cleanup/Test_unijet_customer_data_cleanup
Started
.

Finished in 0.001 seconds.

1 tests, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
100% passed

1000.00 tests/s, 4000.00 assertions/s
```

Any idea how I can get the same output in RubyMine as in the console?

Answer (score 0):

> When I run unit tests from RubyMine

How do you configure it?
If you configure it as a simple ruby script or rake task in `Run`, you will get wrong results (it seems merely tracking execute time instead of checking if tests pass).

Instead you define run/debug configuration in `Test::Unit/Shoulda/MiniTest`.

P.S. I'm using RubyMine 7.0.